# Database backup size conundrum

Tags: sql-server, database, backup

I have a small SQL Server 2005 database. I take daily backup (automated) and the size of the `.bak` file typically comes out to be 400MB, growing by 5MB every day (which is inline with its usages).

Last night the size of the backup file jumped to 1GB. Suspecting that someone was trying to fill the database with garbage data, I ran a report (`Reports -> Standard Reports -> Disk User By Top Tables`) and the total size came out to be around 400MB.

Then thinking maybe something was wrong with the automated backup process, I immediately took backup again but the `.bak` file came out to be over 1GB. Before this automated backup yesterday, an automated task that defragments indexes also ran. However, all these months, a backup after this index optimization used to actually reduce the size of the `.bak` file.

I am trying to find an explanation for this big jump in size overnight and also why the `.bak` file is more than double the size of the the actual database disk usages?

UPDATE: I ran

```
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(mydb)
```

to remove transaction logs. Then took a backup again. The size of the `.bak` file came out even bigger than last time.

This is the query I ran:

```
    DBCC SHRINKFILE(mydb_log, 1)
    BACKUP LOG mydbWITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
    DBCC SHRINKFILE(mydb_log, 1)
```

Comment: There were 1GB of changes while the database data remained about the same. For instance, I believe that if you did something like `UPDATE Table Set Field1 = Field1` would cause a lot of data to be written to log file, yet the data remains unchanged, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: I ran DBCC Shrinkfile again and took another backup.  The backup file is now 2.5GB.  Not sure what is being added to the backup file.

Answer (score 0):

1 - How are you backing up the data?  Maintenance plans?

2 - If you are appending to the same database backup file, the backup will grow!

Check out the contents of the file.

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM AdventureWorksBackups WITH FILE=1;
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx

This assumes you have a dump device named AdventureWorksBackups.  You can also change it to a DISK='AdventureWorks.bak'.

3 - Also, the maintenance plans do not do a good job with determining when to re-organize/update stats versus rebuild an index.

4 - Check out the ola hallengren scripts.  They are way better!

http://ola.hallengren.com/

First, they create a directory structure for you.

```
c:\backup\<server name>\<database name>\full
c:\backup\<server name>\<database name>\diff
c:\backup\<server name>\<database name>\log
```

Second, each backup has a date time stamp.  No appending to backup files.

Third, they clean up after themselves by passing the number of hours to keep on-line.

Fourth, they handle index fragmentation better - 5-30 = re-organize or 30+ = rebuild.

I usually set up the following for my databases.

1 - system databases - full backup every night, log backups hourly.

2 - user databases - full backup 1 x week, diff backup x 6 days, log backups hourly

Last but not least, SQL Server 2005 does not have native support for compressed backups.  This does not mean you can not run a batch file to zip them up afterwards.

Third party tools like QUEST (DELL) and RED GATE used to support their own backup utility.  The main reason was to fill this gap.  Since SQL Server 2008, compressed backups were available.  I think many of the vendors are getting rid of this utility since it is now standard.

Comment: Every backup go to a different file (date time stamp). And I use the IndexOptimize script from .hallengren weekly.

Comment: What are you using?  Maintenance plans?  What is the recovery model?

Comment: For backup, yes, maintenance plan.  Full backup runs every night. ola.hallengren.com script to optimize indexes runs every week.

Comment: Use DBCC SHRINKDATABASE with care.  It just moves everything from the end of the file to the front.  Causes a bunch of fragmentation.  I always leave 20-25% overhead in the data file so that there is room to growth and have my indexes not fragmented.

Comment: What is the current size of the log?  Is that what is growing?  http://craftydba.com/?p=3033  Check out my blog article on shrinking the log when there is an open transaction.

Comment: Also, what are the growth options?  sp_helpdb [AdventureWorks2012]?  They should be in MB not %.  Otherwise you have VLFs issues in the transaction log.

Comment: I don't care much about the log file growth.  What I care about is the size of .bak file that jumped last night for no apparent reasons (only thing took place was index defrag prior to taking this snapshot) and it trippled after I ran DBCC Shrinkdatabase.

Comment: Hi Allen, unfortunately the moderator deleted the post on backup file sizes.  So the info in msdb.dbo.backupset says the database full backup is 1677 mb?  Is that correct?  Just do a sp_helpdb to see the sizes of the data files (*.ndf, *.mdf).  What do they add up to? - J

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44114/discussion-between-crafty-dba-and-allen-king)